# Can't vote from ledger using a hardware wallet?

Tags: polkadot-js, signing, ledger, hardware

I tried to vote from a ledger kusama account on polkadot js and I get `Raw data signing is not supported for hardware wallets`. Is this a limitation of the zondax ledger app or a polkadot-js limitation?

Comment: Maybe this comment https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension/issues/1025#issuecomment-1066056797 from Jaco (back from March 2022) on a similar error msg is helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Ledger Raw data signing is not supported for hardware wallets
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/signing